# I have installed the "Stack Overflow" Gadget on Windows 7, but it does not seem to do anything

Tags: support, windows-7, windows-gadget

I have the [Stack Overflow Windows gadget](http://gallery.live.com/results.aspx?bt=1&q=stack%20overflow%20gadget) running on my Windows 7 desktop; I have entered my User ID, but still the gadget does nothing.

Was this a government stimulus project?

Comment: Stack Overflow Windows Gadget?

Comment: @Grace, link to gallery/gadget edited into OP.

Comment: You might want to contact the developer of the gadget directly. http://insomniacgeek.com/a-stack-overflow-sidebar-gadget/

Comment: Gadgets are supposed to *do* stuff? I thought their purpose was simply to sit there, impotently, behind all of your open windows, and perhaps suck up a bit of otherwise-unused RAM when you let your cursor slip into the corner...

Comment: Well, gadgets should (IMHO) at least convey some useful (?) information... Time/Temperature/Location of Paris Hilton's undergarments (if any), CPU usage, Netflix Queue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it just displays your flair and rep. Judging from the screenshots (and the date on the post - over two years ago) it was written before the super collider. Since gadgets are just HTML it could be updated to show the super collider - I might even use that myself.

Comment: I had higher hopes for it than that.. but I think your are right.

Answer (score 2):

That gadget is of no big use. However if you want to see something enter your UserId number. Click on your userId in the top , this will take you to your profile page. There in the top-right you can see your user-id. Enter that in the gadget and it shows up your reputations

Comment: @prassan, got that all figured out a month ago. I know what it actually does..I just expected it to do 'more'.