# Is there a Stack Exchange status gadget for the Windows Sidebar?

Tags: discussion, global-inbox, windows-gadget

I've already seen the gadget that shows information about users. What I need is a gadget that notifies me of new events, like the Stack Exchange global inbox (on the left top corner of each page) does.

Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use any RSS-viewing gadget and point it at the feed that interests you.

Comment: i don't need rss feeds. i just want to be noticed when someone comments my question/answer or answers my question

Comment: ah, yes. Like me, you want the super-collider dropdown in a gadget. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93537/i-have-installed-the-stack-overflow-gadget-on-windows-7-but-it-does-not-seem/93542#93542  Don't think anyone is volunteering to do that one.

Comment: i don't need anybody to write it for me, i can do it myself. i was just wondering maybe there already is something like this

Comment: well, [this guy volunteered](http://stackapps.com/questions/1928/i-am-planning-to-build-a-windows-7-gadget-for-stack-exchange), but whether or not it actually exists… ?